# If $f(x)$ is a diff. function $ \int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt = 2\left[\alpha f(\alpha^2)+\beta f(\beta^2)\right]$

Tags: calculus

> If the function $f:\left[0,4\right]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable then show that
>
> $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt = 2\left[\alpha f(\alpha^2)+\beta f(\beta^2)\right]\;\; \forall \; 0\; <\alpha,\beta <2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt\;,$ Now put $t=u^2\,$ Then $dt=2udu$

So we get $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{2}2f(u^2)f(u)du$

Now Let $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_{0}^{2}2f(u^2)f(u)du$.

Given $F(x)$ is differentiable function in $\left(0,2\right)$. So it is continuous in $\left[0,2\right]$

So By Using $\bf{LMVT}\;,$ in $\mu \in (0,2)$

So $$F'(\mu) = \frac{F(2)-F(0)}{2-0}\Rightarrow f(\mu^2)\cdot 2\mu = \frac{\int_{0}^{2}f(u^2)2udu}{2}$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: You want to write $\exists 0<α,β<2$, the statement is clearly not true "for all". -- There is always only one $f$ inside the integrand. -- Are there any conditions on $α,β$? If not, your solution $α=β=μ$ is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write $\exists$ $0<\alpha<\beta<2$ instead of $\forall$ $0<\alpha<\beta<2$.

Write $t=u^2$, $dt=2udu$, $\int_0^4f(t)dt=\int_0^22uf(u^2)du$. You can write $\int_0^22uf(u^2)du = \int_0^12uf(u^2)du+\int_1^22uf(u^2)du$.

The mean value theorem implies that there exists $\alpha\in (0,1)$ such that $\int_0^12uf(u^2)du =(1-0)2\alpha f(\alpha^2)$ and $\beta\in (1,2)$ such that $\int_1^22uf(u^2)du = (2-1)2\beta f(\beta^2)$.

We deduce that $\int_0^4f(t)dt = \int_0^22uf(u^2)du =2[\alpha f(\alpha^2)+\beta f(\beta^2)]$, $0<\alpha<\beta<2$.

Comment: Thanks Tsemo Aristide, would you explain me the line $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}2uf(u^2)du = (1-0)2\alpha f(\alpha^2)$(Means how can we get it.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals

Answer (score 1):

After repairing all the inconsistencies in your write-up, your solution $α=β=μ$ seems to be correct.

You could, if you want to get non-equal $α$ and $β$, split the integration interval in the middle and apply the same arguments.